# Two different versions of PHP on Centos 6 64 - what are my options

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have a real dilemma here folks.  This is the first time i have set up my own dedicated server so im pretty green but i have learned alot and made some mistakes along the way.  One of those mistakes is that somehow i ended up with two different versions of PHP on my server.  I think that possibly kaltura video server or something else i installed also installed PHP as well because i did not do this intentionally.

```
 /usr/bin/php 5.3 zend 2.3
 /usr/bin/php-cgi 


 /usr/local/bin/php  5.6  zend 2.6
 /usr/local/bin/php-cgi
 /usr/local/bin/php-config
 /usr/local/bin/phpize
```

Now im not sure what to do here because i dont know which one to get rid of and i dont think both of them will support my apache.

```
 Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

So im in a real pickle here i think.  I would rather have PHP 5.5 because i think that 5.5 would support my apache and also be more secure and up to date then 5.3  here are my concerns

5.6 wont support my apache and i have no clue how to update apache and im not sure if i can handle that, plus 5.6 has alot of changes that my software may have problems with.

5.3 is less secure and is very very old and running on alot of deprecated items and since i am running webmin and installed it with webmin i can uninstall 5.3 packages easy enough via the webmin menu but what do i do then.

I could update 5.3 to 5.5 but again i have no clue how to do that properly.

I could remove all of it and then install 5.5 but i have no idea if that will break apache or mysql and i dont know how to install PHP 5.5 and compile it and all of that stuff via command line, my yum only has 5.3

Im sure ill have to remove php 5.6 but i have no idea how to do that or what is dependant on it.

So on a Linux CentOS 6 64 bit 
with mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

What would you do?

Any advise would be really appreciated, thanks so much

Comment: You want the newest version of php that is offered by your software management system.

Comment: Obviously you performed "wild installations" in your system. So instead of using the software management system you directly or indirectly wrote files right into your file system which is a very bad idea for many, many reasons (talking about software installation here when referring to "files"). You should remove the stuff "installed" to `/usr/local...`.

Comment: And a general remark: your apache http server can work with any php version you chose, assuming that you install it _correctly_ with all details that are required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how should i go about removing the /usr/local items, via file manage or is there a linux uninstall command for 5.6 (apache was installed via webmin so im sure thats ok)

Comment: Since you wrote the files in a wild manner we don't know about, we cannot say if that "installation" also provided an `uninstall` script or similar. One of the issues with such approach is that you have no control about such a collection of files wildly written in your file system. So no reliable way to remove or upgrade them. Please note that his is not Linux' fault.

Comment: I understand that i messed up here, hard lesson to learn.  I dont really remember installing it but i could have in one of my late night debacle's, it could have been when i thought i was updating it, that was a month ago so i dont remember.  There is a php dir in /usr/local so i could start with that and i guess if something breaks then ill fix it and only blame myself.  But to the 5.3 version, should i update that to 5.5 or just remove everything and reinstall php and is there a good resource out there how to do so?

Comment: Em... You _do_ know about your systems "software management system"? How software management actually works in typical Linux systems? Don't get this wrong, but I have the impression that you did not fully understand the difference I pointed out above. You definitely should learn about that stuff. Start by finding out what distribution you are using and what type of software management is available on your system. Then _use that_.

Comment: i may have to google that "software management system" because when you say that, to me it means using webmin.  But what i think you might be talking about (i dont know it by that name) is that certain things go in certain places in the linux file system. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using on that system?

Comment: Is this what you need?cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Comment: So you are using a `CentOS` distribution. That one is RedHat based, thus the native package format is `rpm`. There are several management systems available. You will probably prefer a command line version, unless you have a graphical console which does not really make much sense in a server targeted system setup. Do you can either use `yum` or the raw `rpm` command. A good starting point to read into the matter is that: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/pt-pkg-management.html

Comment: And a side note: this is a site dedicated to _programming related issues_. You will probably get _much_ more and better results over at the `SuperUser` sister page which deals with general hard and software issues:  http://superuser.com/  Or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From doing some reading today on those links as well as other places i first removed php 5.3 using webmin so thats gone.  Then i did a search of php  whereis php php: /usr/src/php/php.ini-development /usr/src/php/php.ini-production /usr/src/php/php.gif /usr/src/php/php5.spec /etc/php.d /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/php and then i did a file manager search of the server files for anything php-5 and it only shows two places, one was /var/lib/yum which is the php 5.3 and the other was in a dir i remember making for original copies of sources which is the 5.6.25.tar file.

Comment: So from other reading it appears that i can either try to do a make uninstall from the /usr/local/bin dir and if that does not work then just delete the files manually.

Comment: I also just read that when you upgrade from apache 2.2 to 2.4 that php 5.6 comes with it. So maybe thats the best thing to do im not sure. The problem is that so many ways of doing this end up leaving you with two versions of apache on your system and thats not what i want.

Comment: You are right about the removal. Use `webmin`, try the provided `uninstall` command, can't really do much damage. Try to clear all left overs... Roughly I'd say anything under /usr/local/... can be removed. That location in the local file system is specifically reserved for _local_ installations meant to overwrite system installations. Also everything related to sources can be removed. For any normal usage you do _not_ need sources!

Comment: Apache 2.4 is pretty much standard these days, 2.6 is rolling out. 2.2 is clearly outdated. The version of php5 provided for your distribution depends a bit on the repositories you integrated (activated). But in general you should stick with the main repositories, those offer stable and reliable packages specifically prepared to work for your specific distribution, system and software collection. You should _not_ follow some of those guides that try to do everything manually. There is no need to install php manually. _Use your software management system_.

Comment: The advantage of using those packages (in contrast to "wild installations") is that they are more or less guaranteed to work, will be upgraded automatically in a safe manner and that their dependencies are considered. All of this will _not_ work for wild installations. For example upgrading apache from 2.2 to 2.4 can (usually) be done with a single click in your software management. That system will point out additional requirements, resolve them (if possible), so that you only have to accept.

Comment: Thanks, yes i almost wish i had gone debian due to apt-get deal where it does it for you. I have checked into joining Red Hat which will help with that process.  Yes i serioulsly need to update yum. There are quite a few packages in webmin i have not installed so i need to look into that too.  Webmin tells me that php-pecl-zip(x86-64) is needed as a dependency but i cant find it for el6 anywhere,  i can find  el5 but i dont know if that will work or not, have looked in rpmfind and others. This series of videos has helped me alot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwRs_6U8MDQ  All php is gone now.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot follow that mess. Debian or RedHat does not really make any difference.